# Quick method to correct Entity Framework's missed "singularizations"?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Given the need to "Update Model from Database" fairly frequently from the .edmx diagram, is there a way to modify the rules by which Visual Studio attempts to "singularize" the entities?

An example would be the `aspnet_Users` entity which is never corrected to become its singular form of `aspnet_User`.  I'm tiring of manually correcting this name in not only the entity itself, but the 10 or 12 navigation properties involving this entity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Entity Developer](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/). We provide flexible Naming Rules: [image]
<sub>(source: [devart.com](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/images/model-settings-df.jpg))</sub>
 I've just performed a test, and aspnet_users table was named AspnetUser in the conceptual model.

Comment: Was this using the free version?

Comment: @PolishedTurd, the only limitation of the Express version is the model size. You can download it and try out the Naming Rules functionality.